# SoX on Windows 11 - No default audio device configured

Tags: audio-recording, sox

I've installed SoX (https://sox.sourceforge.net/) in order to be able to process microphone input via node. I'm trying the most basic settings, for example, recording from the default audio device using this simple command line: `sox --default-device test.wav`.

This generates the error "FAIL sox: Sorry, there is no default audio device configured"

I can force SoX to use a specific device using this: `sox -t waveaudio 0 test.wav` so I know SoX is installed correctly.

In Windows (11) I can see I have my USB Microphone set up and configured as the default device.

The more verbose output (with `-V6` enabled) shows the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-2\sox.exe DBUG sox: Looking for a default device: trying format `waveaudio'
C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-2\sox.exe DBUG waveaudio: waveOutOpen(QUERY: Dev -1 0Hz 0Ch 8Prec 8Wide) returned 32
C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-2\sox.exe FAIL sox: Sorry, there is no default audio device configured
```

So it's looking at the list of `waveaudio` devices and coming up empty. What gives?

(I'm using GitBash as my command shell if that's of any relevance)

Comment: I'm not loving my solution (because it doesn't make sense) but editing the System Variables and adding a variable called `AUDIODRIVER` with a value of `waveaudio` sorted me out. I didn't even need the `AUDIODEV` variable for it to work.

Comment: I was having a similar issue, and this worked for me as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing the System Variables and adding a variable called AUDIODRIVER with a value of waveaudio sorted me out.

I didn't even need the AUDIODEV variable for it to work.